# Adjust created div to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make width of the created div adjust to parent div when width of the parent div changes.
For example when my web page shrinks created div (kind of caption) overflow parent div.

[image]

```
var $discDiv = $("<div></div>");
$discDiv.css({
  width:$(".col-md-8").width(),
  height:$(".col-md-8").height()*0.3,
  backgroundColor:"blue",
  position:"absolute",
  zIndex: 1,
  opacity:0,

});
$(".col-md-8").append($discDiv);

$(".col-md-8").mouseenter(function() {
  $discDiv.css({
  opacity:0.3

  });

});
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/full/xOPyZR/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `width` to percentage value

```
$discDiv.css({
  width:$(".col-md-8").width(),
  height:"100%",
  backgroundColor:"blue",
  position:"absolute",
  zIndex: 1,
  opacity:0
});
```

and add mouse leave for better rendering :

```
$(".col-md-8").mouseleave(function() {
  $discDiv.css({
     opacity:0
  });
});
```